# ProtectedData.Protect vs DataProtectionProvider Windows Phone 8 Silverlight to Windows Phone 8.1 Universal App migration

Tags: c#, security, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

My old(WP-8.0-Silverlight) application uses `ProtectedData.Protect` method to save data in secure way. I want to upgrade my existing app to Windows Phone Universal App. In WinRT `ProtectedData.Protect` is not available because there is a new API `DataProtectionProvider` that isn't compatible with Silverlight implementation.

**The first question is: How can I migrate data to the new application?**
As I said Silverlight API is not compatible with new WinRT API and causes exception during unprotecting data.

I'm considering updating existing app with WP-8.0-Silverlight update that will use `ProtectedData(crypt32)` API and use other algorithm to migrate and save new data to storage. Later on my new WinRT app will be able to decrypt this data.

**The second question is: Which algorithms should I use to provide best security?**

Comment: Have you tried adding System.Security.dll. as a reference . That should make ProtectedData available.

Comment: Hi adding previous library for protectedData (from silverlight API) does the job but certification fails.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no built-in ability for migrating.
The Windows Phone Universal App is a totally different app than the WP-8.0-Silverlight App.

A solution is to push your data from Silverlight to something like OneDrive,then import them back to the Windows Phone Universal App.

Answer (score 0):

`DataProtectionProvider` [class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.security.cryptography.dataprotection.dataprotectionprovider.aspx) represents a `cryptographic` provider that can be used to asynchronously encrypt and `decrypt` static data or a data stream.

**You can use the class to protect data to any of the following:**

1. You can use a `security descriptor (SID)` or a `security descriptor definition language (SDDL)` string to protect data to an `Active Directory (AD)` security principal such as an `AD` group. Any member of the group can decrypt the data.
2. You can protect data to the local user or computer account. You can
   protect data to the credentials (password) used during logon to a
   website.

The Windows Phone Universal App is a totally different app than the WP-8.0-Silverlight App.There is no built-in ability for migrating.

You have two options when you begin the porting process.

One is to edit a copy of your existing project files, including the app package manifest. The other option is to create a new Windows 10 project in Visual Studio and copy your files into it.

[Migrate apps to the Universal Windows Platform (UWP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt148501.aspx)

[Porting a Windows Runtime 8.x project to a UWP project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/w8x-to-uwp-porting-to-a-uwp-project)